# Reading value from app/web.config in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core-1.0

Created asp.net core web application. In this existing class library converted nuget package and installed. 
how to assign appsettings key value to class library from asp.net core app.

Answer (score 1):

From the asp.net docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

Write a Constructor in your StartUp.cs, just like you would do with the 'older' versions of asp.net core.

```
public class Startup
{
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Adds services required for using options.
    services.AddOptions();
 ...
```

Create a appsettings.json if not already exist.

Just for Example:
    {
      "key1" : "value1"
    }

Read it with 
    Configuration["key1"]

If you need the Configuration in any of your Controller, have a look at the DI in ASP:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection